# We have a system of linearly independent vectors: $x, y, z$. Determine, whether system $x, x+y, x + y + z$ is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, we have linearly independent vectors $x,y,z$, so for  $x, x+y, x + y + z$ if I cannot express $x$ using the other two vectors (there is no way to express $x$ using $x+y$ and $x+y+z$, as far as I am concerned) does it mean, that system $x, x+y, x + y + z$ is actually linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ in $\Bbb R$ such that

$$\alpha x+\beta(x+y)+\gamma(x+y+z)=0\iff(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x+(\beta+\gamma)y+\gamma z=0$$
and since the vectors are linearly independent then
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\beta+\gamma=\gamma=0\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$$
and then the vectors $x,x+y,x+y+z$ are also linearly independent.

An other method to see the result is to compute the determinant of these vectors in the basis $(x,y,z)$
$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right|=1\ne0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$
  u = x+y,\, v = x+y+z \text{.}
$$

It's not sufficient to check that $x$ cannot be expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$, you need to show *none* of the vectors $x$, $u$, $v$ can be expressed in terms of the other two. For example, $u$ and $v$ cound be linearly dependent, but both be linearly independent from $x$. And you'd have to *rigorously* prove that these vectors aren't expressive in terms of the others, not just say "well, it doesn't look like they can". This can get a bit messy, if you attempt it directly.

A somewhat easier approach, is to first observe that we surely have $$
  \textrm{span } \{x,u,v\} \subset \textrm{span } \{x,y,z\} \text{,}
$$
because if we can express some vector $a$ in terms $x,u,v$, then we just have to plug in the definitions of $u,v$ to find an expression in terms of $x,y,z$.

If we can additionally show that we can express $x,y,z$ in terms of $x,u,v$, then it follows that we also have $$
  \textrm{span }\{x,y,z\} \subset \textrm{span }\{x,u,v\} \text{,}
$$
and therefore that $$
  \textrm{span }\{x,y,z\} = \textrm{span }\{x,u,v\} \text{.}
$$
Now, since $x,y,z$ are linearly independent, the subspace on the left-hand side is three-dimensional. But then $x,u,v$ must be linearly independent also, if they too are supposed to span a three-dimensional space.

And we indeed *can* express $x,y,z$ in terms of $x,u,v$, because $$
  y = u - x,\, z = v - u \text{.}
$$
So by the above, $x,u,v$ are linearly independent.